# Put EF7 in a library

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

Julia Lerman often splits her solutions up so she has EF in a class library for it self and then can Work on it through a console app.
I also like when EF is separated from my MVC project, but there are not much help on doing this. It feels like EF7 is thought to only be embedded within MVC6.

When I split my solution up into a library for EF7, a console app and a MVC6 project and afterwards wants to enable Migration, I have to include a startup.cs (it doesn't have to contain anything - just being present) and a project.json with a connection string. If I don't do that, I can't run the command: `dnx ef add migration InitialDatabase`

Is it still okay to split up EF and MVC or do I have to rethink my logic?

For inspiration and commenting - here's my DBContext:

```
namespace Model
{
    public class ModelCnt : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        //Include Cofiguration so I can get connectionstring fram appsettings.json
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

            //Initialize configuration:
            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();

            //Add connectionstring saved within enviroment variable:
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString"]);
        }
    }
}
/// <summary>Is necesary for the Migration to work</summary>
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure() { }
}
```

Comment: I don't have enough for an answer, but yes you should go down this route for all non-trivial projects and doing so lends itself well to SOLID and DRY principals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should go down this route for all non-trivial projects and doing so lends itself well to SOLID and DRY principals.  Doing so not only allows you to access the data layer from other projects within your solution as you suggest, but also paves the way for other solutions to use that library in the future if needed also.

Considering MVC 6 is so new, I can't find any examples of an n-tier application.  However the principals of the [older versions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En) still apply.  At Microsoft Connect 2015 a couple of days ago, Scott Hanselman demoed a *Health Clinic* application that looked to have the data layer in a separate project.  [This](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5AndNETCoreRC1InContextPlusAllTheConnect2015News.aspx) post notes that they intend to have the code for that demo online soon.

In the meantime, you can try yourself.  Create a solution with an MVC 6 templated project in it.  Then create a new Class Library (Package) for the Data layer, and move the EntityFramework references from your MVC6 project's project.json to the Data project's project.json.  Move across your `ModelCnt` as above, and reference the Data project from the MVC6 project.  The `ef` dnx command should still be available directly via your MVC6 project, but you can stick `"ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"` in your Data project's project.json if you wish to access it from there also.

Comment: Thank you for interesting reply. It works okay in a library for itself. But I have decided to let the model be in MVC6. If it grows, I can take it out in a library.
I can edit the model from a console app by referencing the mvc6 project and I don’t have plans for using the model in other projects. I must rethink my normal workflow – and that’s sometimes healthy.